# Unable to load the css files using Grunt

Tags: gruntjs

```
[enter image description here][1]


I am not able to load the css files using gruntfile.js

Below is my gruntfile

'use strict';
module.exports = function(grunt) {
require('time-grunt')(grunt);


// Automatically load required Grunt tasks
require('jit-grunt')(grunt);
grunt.initConfig({
  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
  jshint: {
    options: {
      jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
      reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
    },

    all: {
      src: [
        'Gruntfile.js',
        'app/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
      ]
    }
  },
  copy: {
      dist: {
        cwd: 'app',
        src: [ '**','!styles/**/*.css','!scripts/**/*.js' ],
        dest: 'dist',
        expand: true
      },
    },
    clean: {
        build:{
            src: [ 'dist/']
        }
    },
     useminPrepare: {
        html: 'app/index.html',
        options: {
            dest: 'dist'
        }
    },
      // Concat
    concat: {
        options: {
            separator: ';'
        },
        // dist configuration is provided by useminPrepare
        dist: {}
    },
     concat: {
        options: {
            separator: ';'
        },
        // dist configuration is provided by useminPrepare
        dist: {}
    },
      // Uglify
    uglify: {
        // dist configuration is provided by useminPrepare
        dist: {}
    },
    cssmin: {
        dist: {}
    },
     filerev: {
        options: {
            encoding: 'utf8',
            algorithm: 'md5',
            length: 20
        },
        release: {
            // filerev:release hashes(md5) all assets (images, js and css )
            // in dist directory
            files: [{
                src: [
                    'dist/scripts/*.js',
                    'dist/styles/*.css',
                ]
            }]
        }
    },
      // Usemin
      // Replaces all assets with their revved version in html and css files.
      // options.assetDirs contains the directories for finding the assets
      // according to their relative paths
    usemin: {
        html: ['dist/html/*.html'],
        css: ['dist/styles/*.css'],
        options: {
            assetsDirs: ['dist', 'dist/styles']
        }
    },
       watch: {
        copy: {
            files: [ 'app/**', '!app/**/*.css', '!app/**/*.js'],
            tasks: [ 'build' ]
        },
        scripts: {
            files: ['app/scripts/app.js'],
            tasks:[ 'build']
        },
        styles: {
            files: ['app/styles/app.css'],
            tasks:['build']
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
            },
            files: [
                'app/{,*/}*.html',
                '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                'app/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
            ]
      }
    },
     connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: 'localhost',
        livereload: 35729
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          base:{
               path: 'dist',
            options: {
                index: 'index.html',
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
});

grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean',
    'jshint',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concat',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'copy',
    'filerev',
    'usemin'
]);
grunt.registerTask('serve',['build','connect:dist','watch']);
grunt.registerTask('default',['build']);
};

Below is my folder structure
[enter image description here][2]
```

I am trying to load the webpage but it's showing plane html without any css.
Can anyone tell me what needs to be done to fix this?
When I am trying to load the file using grunt serve it's showing me 404 error